# parse a values from json data

Tags: json, node.js

Am trying to get values from a `json` data using `node.js`

Following is the json data(It is dynamic), it may contains names like `tcp,ipp,http,udp,https` .here i only displaying `tcp` and `ipp` only

```
sample json

[ { '$':
     { name: 'tcp',
       showname: 'tnternet crinting Protocol',
       size: '584',
       pos: '202' },
    field: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { '$':
     { name: 'ipp',
       showname: 'Internet Printing Protocol',
       size: '584',
       pos: '202' },
    field: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

i need to get the details of `ipp` only .

(any other methods without using `sample[1]` ,like `name =ipp` from the json data)

```
example

{ '$':
   { name: 'ipp',
     showname: 'Internet Printing Protocol',
     size: '584',
     pos: '202' },
  field:
   [ { '$': [Object] },
     { '$': [Object] },
     { '$': [Object] },
     { '$': [Object], field: [Object] },
     { '$': [Object], field: [Object] },
     { '$': [Object] } ] }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using lodash as follows:

```
  var result = _.result(_.find(list, { '$': {'name':'ipp'} }), '$');
```

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/unh9wZuDCnIETE7EWHmD?p=preview

Lodash:
https://lodash.com/docs#find

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to iterate, and look for the name

```
var ipp = null;

sample.forEach(function(o) {
    if (  o['$'].name === 'ipp' ) {
        ipp = o;
        return false;
    }
});

// ipp === object here
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/obtx26pn/)